# Making a table horizontally scrollable without changing the existing CSS properties

Tags: html, html-table, rows, horizontal-scrolling

Please help me make this table horizontally scrollable without changing the existing CSS properties. The existing CSS is changing rows to column and I want to keep it that way only.

```
<style>

tr{

display:block;
float:left;
}
td,th{
display: block;
   border: 1px solid #ddd;
   clear:both
}


</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you add css properties?

Comment: The CSS you're using completely _destroys_ the table. Please indicate why you are doing this! If you want a scrollable table, you should put it into a scrollable `<div>`, but you shouldn't alter the `display` of the table elements.

Comment: Hi Aloso , I have written that css because I am alternating rows and columns.Run the code once then you will be able to understand.

Comment: @pistou css is already there.

Comment: I would like to  request people to not to down vote this only because they are not able to understand my scenario. I think this is very useful and other people might get some help from this If they want to alternate the display of rows and column. I also found the css which I have written from one of the questions only

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like @yoursweater already suggested. See the code snippet for an example.

```html
<style>
  thead {
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  tbody {
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: 73px;
  }
  
  tr {
    display: block;
    float: left;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    clear: both
  }
</style>

<body>


  <div class="container">
    <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
    <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cristophs0n "display:flex" did the trick now its working fine. But I am not able to fix the first column. If I use position property then rest of the table is coming below.Could you please help me in fixing this also.

Comment: Yeah sure, no probs!  What do you mean by fix the first column though?

Comment: Basically I dont want heading to be scrollable. FirstName,LastName,Email are like heading so I want to freeze it like we do in excel.

Comment: No worries, check and see if the updated code snippet is what you require.

Comment: No probs at all.  If you are happy with it could you maybe except the answer.  Thanks

Comment: I have accepted it already but because of low credits its not reflecting

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean by "horizontally scrollable"? Assuming I understand what you're asking, if you put the table within a parent div, you can specify the dimensions with CSS and then set `overflow: scroll;` and `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent div to create horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Hi @yourweather I tried that but the thing is I was displaying row and columns as block level elements, So the whole structure was not coming  properly. After adding display:flex in tbody it worked. But now I am not able to fix my first column. I would appreciate your help on this.